# Tensorflow not using all system memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory

I am trying to load rather big h5 files using tensorflow dataset API.

My biggest tensor is about 800MB in memory (complex-valued `32x15x640x322`).

When loading it, tensorflow gives me the following warning:

```
2020-05-05 17:41:32.662641: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 791347200 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

However my system has a RAM of 251GB (from `htop`), so 800MB is nowhere close to 10% of the system memory. I don't understand why this warning pops up.

Many of the current solutions for this problem suggest reducing the batch size, but this is not my problem. I want to understand why I have this warning even though it seems I have enough memory.

If anyone wants to reproduce this, you just need to install my package from GitHub (`!pip install git+https://github.com/zaccharieramzi/fastmri-reproducible-benchmark`). You can then run the following code:

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

from fastmri_recon.data.utils.h5 import from_multicoil_train_file_to_image_and_kspace_and_contrast

K_shape_single_coil = (32, 640, 322)
K_shape_multi_coil = (32, 15, 640, 322)
I_shape = (32, 320, 320)
contrast = 'CORPD_FBK'

def create_data(filename, multicoil=False):
    k_shape = K_shape_single_coil
    image_ds = "reconstruction_esc"
    if multicoil:
        k_shape = K_shape_multi_coil
        image_ds = "reconstruction_rss"
    kspace = np.random.normal(size=k_shape) + 1j * np.random.normal(size=k_shape)
    image = np.random.normal(size=I_shape)
    kspace = kspace.astype(np.complex64)
    image = image.astype(np.float32)
    with h5py.File(filename, "w") as h5_obj:
        h5_obj.create_dataset("kspace", data=kspace)
        h5_obj.create_dataset(image_ds, data=image)
        h5_obj.attrs['acquisition'] = contrast

n_files = 5
for i in range(n_files):
    create_data(f'test_{i}.h5', multicoil=True)


path = './'


files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(f'{path}*.h5', seed=0)

res = next(iter(files_ds))

rand = False
parallel = False
inner_slices = None

selection = [
    {'inner_slices': inner_slices, 'rand': rand},  # slice selection
    {'rand': parallel, 'keep_dim': False},  # coil selection
]
def _tf_filename_to_image_and_kspace_and_contrast(filename):
    def _from_train_file_to_image_and_kspace_and_contrast_tensor_to_tensor(filename):
        filename_str = filename.numpy()
        image, kspace, contrast = from_multicoil_train_file_to_image_and_kspace_and_contrast(
            filename_str,
            selection=selection,
        )
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(image), tf.convert_to_tensor(kspace), tf.convert_to_tensor(contrast)
    [image, kspace, contrast] = tf.py_function(
        _from_train_file_to_image_and_kspace_and_contrast_tensor_to_tensor,
        [filename],
        [tf.float32, tf.complex64, tf.string],
    )
    if rand:
        n_slices = (1,)
    else:
        n_slices = (inner_slices,)
    if parallel:
        kspace_size = (640, None)
    else:
        kspace_size = (15, 640, None)
    image_size = (320, 320)
    image.set_shape(n_slices + image_size)
    kspace.set_shape(n_slices + kspace_size)
    return image, kspace, contrast

filename = res.numpy().decode("utf-8")
image, kspace, contrast = _tf_filename_to_image_and_kspace_and_contrast(filename)
```

The last function would of course be within the dataset but I put it out for the purpose of this example.

This is done with python 3.6.10, tf 2.1.

Comment: What system are you using that has so much RAM?

Comment: haha it's just a computer that my company bought.

Comment: That does not really answer my question, I wanted to know if it really has that much physical RAM. Also there could be memory quotas for your user that do not allow you to access all RAM. All details matter.

Comment: ha ok sure, that's a good point since I am on a shared network. How can I know how much RAM I actually have access to? To give the 251GB number I used both `htop` and `free -h`.

Comment: Looking at the output of `ulimit -a` I don't think I have any restriction coming from this. Same when looking at `limits.conf`.

Comment: It is however interesting to note that on my laptop with 32GB of RAM this warning doesn't appear with the same code (slightly different python version though 3.6.8).